# How should I approach updating data properties in vue, computed and watcher doesn't seem to be doing it

Tags: vue.js, axios, computed-properties

I am struggling to update some filed inputs on a form I am working on. I get the data back from axios in one data property and I am trying to prefill some fields with the response. I get four fields back from the server and want to keep everything the same v-model on the inputs, so I can submit a two prefilled fields with all of my form data.

I have tried setting a watcher on the data when it gets returned but that seems to get me nowhere, I now have a computed method that should update my data properties when Axios gets a response.

```
data() {
  pluResponse: {},
  item: {
    plu: '',
    commodity: '',
  },
},

handlePLUInput(event) {
  axios.post(API_SEARCH_ENDPOINT,
    this.item,
    { headers: {
        'Content-type' : 'application/json',
     }
     }).then(response => {
       this.pluResponse = response.data.data[0];
     }).catch(error => {console.log(error)};
},

computed: {
  item(pluResponse) {
    this.item.plu = pluResponse.plu;
    this.item.commodity = pluResponse.commodity;
  }
}
```

I'm not getting any error messages the item data property just doesn't seem to update. Computed isn't getting fired off maybe?

Comment: computed property by default don't receive values and always should return any value. why not assign to item object inside of `then()`?

Comment: my data structure is very different in item than in response. I could try I spose.

Comment: Yeah from the api cal I am getting back a few fields with different keys then I want to submit the larger form with a bung more data back to the database when filled out, I guess I could adjust my data somehow, change around some keys.

Answer (score 1):

I mean you could do this:

```
handlePLUInput(event) {
  axios.post(API_SEARCH_ENDPOINT,
    this.item,
    { headers: {
        'Content-type' : 'application/json',
     }
     }).then(response => {
       this.pluResponse = response.data.data[0];
       this.item.plu = this.pluResponse.plu;
       this.item.commodity = this.pluResponse.commodity;
     }).catch(error => {console.log(error)};
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, computed properties must always hold a value. That means any method in `computed` must return a value.

Secondly, It's considered bad practice to introduce side effects in the methods that return value of computed properties, which in your case, is modifying the value of a `data` property. [Here](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-side-effects-in-computed-properties.html) you can learn more about this.

Lastly, as far as I know, you can't have a computed property with the same name as a data property, and I suspect this may be the main cause of the problem you're running into.